# How to give Greater than Date value without passing parameter in JPA Date method

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to fetch records which are greater than actionDate column using Spring JPA.
I am able to achieve it if i write the method like below .

```
findAllByActionDateGreaterThan(Date date)
```

But Is there any way i can do it without passing the date parameter like a Hardcoded value in the method name itself like

```
findAllByActionDateGreaterThanSysdateMinus30()
```

Comment: why not just use @Query annotation ?

Comment: Not used the Query annotation till now in my application , so i just dont want to introduce it now unless its not possible .

Comment: Cannot you make findAllByActionDateGreaterThanSysdateMinus30() a wrapper function for findAllByActionDateGreaterThan()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it is a complicate workaround - but have you tried to use Java Specifications?

```
public class TestSpec implements Specification<YourEntity> {
@Override
public Predicate toPredicate(Root<YourEntity> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
    Predicate yourPredicate
            = cb.and(cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get(dateInEntity), 
    return cb.and(yourPredicate);
}
```

then it should work like this:
yourRepo.findAll(yourPredicate);

here is more about that:
https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl

Answer (score 2):

This may help, inside your interface

```
default List<Object> findAllByActionDateGreaterThanSysdateMinus30() {
    Instant oneMonthAgoInstance = Instant.now()
            .minus(Duration.ofDays(30L));
    Date oneMonthAgoDate = Date.from(oneMonthAgoInstance);
    return this.findAllByActionDateGreaterThan(oneMonthAgoDate);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately no , Is there anyway without passing that date parameter . I have nothing to calculate its a constant value.

Comment: if I understand you correctly, you are trying to fetch all of the records in which their actionDate is greater than 30 days ago? if so I have updated my answer.